# How can I create a formula from drop down list

Tags: excel

Hello I really need help getting the right formula I need.

I need to be able to have a drop down list in one cell and then a formula in the next cell that works out the value.

For example in one cell the drop down list would contain >15, 15-20,20-25,25-30 and so on.  This shows how many miles an employee has travelled.  I'd like the next cell to state a figure for each option of the drop down for example 15-20 miles = £4.75.

Any idea's on how to calculate this would be most helpful and I would be forever in your debt

Laura

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Do you mean something like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko68RF89JVk?

Comment: sorry it's hard to explain when i'm not sure what I mean myself.

Comment: first column will have a drop down option for mileage parameters

Comment: <15, 15-20, 20-25 and so on

Comment: if this wont work with a drop down list I can type them in, that's not the problem.  the problem I've got is that I need excel to put a value in the next cell representing the mileage,  for example <15 = Nil, 15-20 = 4.75, 20-25 = 4.63 and so on?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to use a VLOOKUP formula.

Let cell A1 contains your drop down menu (created with Data->Validation->List then selecting a source which in this case will be B1:B3).

Let B1:B3 contain the miles, so 10,20,30

Let C1:C3 contain the costs, so £1.00, £2.00, £3.00

In D1 you can then type `=VLOOKUP($A$1,$B$1:$C$3,2,FALSE)`. This should display in D1 the cost for the mileage selected in A1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your answer tried to do what you said but it just comes up will "value# in cell D1,

Comment: Sorry it's not working - I've just tried it myself and appears to work ok. See [http://picpaste.com/test-TvjCBl74.jpeg](http://picpaste.com/test-TvjCBl74.jpeg) for an image of my example. Cell D1 shows 2 when not displaying the formula.

Comment: Hi Phil, I've just had another go at your formula and it works if I use whole numbers in column B, however I need to show a range <15, 15-20 and so on but when I put these it column D says N/A??  If you could help me that would be amazing

Comment: Try changing the type of the cells in Column B. If you select the cells->right click->format cells->Number Tab->Select Text->Press OK. This should do it for you.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so, I'd be grateful if you could accept it as an answer. Thanks.